# Actionscript 3 Unexpected modification of Class properties when objects intersect

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript

In my `actionscript 3` Class, I put a private property called **oldX** to hold the initial position of the **MovieClip**. 
When one instance drags on another instance these properties are changed unexpectedly.

```
public class Piece extends MovieClip {
    private var oldX:Number;
    private var oldY:Number;

    public function Piece() {
        //...
        oldX = this.x;
        oldY = this.y;
        //action listeners
    }


    public function startDragging(evt:MouseEvent) { evt.startDrag(true); }    

    public function stopDragging(evt:MouseEvent) { 
        evt.stopDrag(); 
        //when one Piece instance drags on another instance
        trace(oldX); //these are not the original values at this moment
        trace(oldY); //these are not the original values at this moment
    }  
}
```

Please could you explain why this happening.

Answer (score 1):

The only true answer here is that the trace must come from other object. If this is all your code, there is nothing that resets those variables. So the trace is not from the object that you expect.

Use debugger to get the `id` of the object (should be something like Object@1241), match the numbers and see what's going on.

Comment: When one instance drags over another instance this incident happens. Is there something wrong with mouse drag/drop listeners?

Comment: You are correct. Its dragged object's instance name and dropped object's instance name are different. It's because that the other object is added after the dragging object. Please add a solution to this in your answer.

Comment: Hah, I cannot solve your problem like a magician, especially when you haven't provided the entire code. Make some efforts, debug, get the error.. I've answered your question, this is another problem of yours.